# How do I use Finnish keyboard layout on a 101-key keyboard

Tags: keyboard-layout, localization

Finnish keyboard layouts bind `<`, `>` and `|` to the extra `LSGT` key that does not exist on a 101-key keyboard. One option is to use cut and paste for inserting these characters. What other options do I have?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the operating system and specific layout you are using. Some layouts bind these characters to additional keys to support 101-key keyboards. [Freedeskop.org](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xkeyboard-config/tree/symbols/fi) binds these characters to `8`, `9` and `i` using the `alt gr + shift` modifier (see diagram below). For example Ubuntu uses this variation.

[image: extra key bindings for <, > and | on a Finnish keyboard]